# What better way to

Tags: phrase-usage, gerunds, infinitives, infinitive-vs-gerund

Do the following all work? If so, is there any difference?

> What better way to please John than to give him a candy?

> What better way to please John than giving him a candy?

> What better way to please John than by giving him a candy?

Comment: 1 and 3 are better than 2, but just use "candy" rather than "a candy".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 is better than 3, and 3 is better than 2.  See ralph.m's comment under your question.

---

**The reason that 1 is better than 3** (and also better than 2) is a concept called [**parallelism**](https://owl.purdue.edu/owl/general_writing/mechanics/parallel_structure.html).  It means that when a sentence contains a construction like a list or direct comparison of concepts (the word 'than' in your examples introduces a comparison), all the items in the construction should have the same form.  This is more about style than correctness, but it's an important enough stylistic detail to appear on many multiple choice tests.

The classic example of 'faulty parallelism' is something like "Doug likes reading, writing and *to watch movies*."  Here, the sentence would obviously be improved by replacing 'to watch movies' with 'watching movies,' to keep the form consistent across the three activities in the list.

An example with a comparison instead of a list might be, "Jane likes to scuba dive better than *snorkeling*."  To fix the faulty parallelism here, change 'snorkeling' to 'to snorkel.' (Alternatively, you could keep 'snorkeling' and change 'to scuba dive' to 'scuba diving.')

---

I agree with ralph.m that 3 is also better than 2, but I'm not as confident as to *why* that is.  Maybe because the preposition *by* breaks up the construction which would otherwise be faulty parallelism?  In 2, you're directly comparing 'to please' with 'giving,' while in 3, you're comparing 'to please' with a prepositional phrase.  Maybe this sounds better because the prepositional phrase construction is different enough from the infinitive to not register as a (failed) attempt at parallelism, while the gerund 'giving' is similar enough to make the reader think, "That should really be replaced with 'to give.'"